# pivotal tracker email integration hook in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pivotaltracker

we are with a simple requirement to be able to create a story in PivotalTracker when an email goes is sent to our org id like say bugs@my-org.com

I could find couple or ruby based wrappers but nothing in java which I can run on our GAE app. Any advise if any such solution exists?

There are some api mention at 
https://www.pivotaltracker.com/help/api?version=v3#add_story with code in curl

```
curl -H "X-TrackerToken: $TOKEN" -X POST -H "Content-type: application/xml" \
    -d "<story><story_type>feature</story_type><name>Fire torpedoes</name><requested_by>James Kirk</requested_by></story>" \
    http://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v3/projects/$PROJECT_ID/stories
```

not sure how do we do it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. [Receive email](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving) in GAE
2. Make a POST request via URLFetch:

   ```
   String pivotalUrl = "http://www.pivotaltracker.com/services/v3/projects/"+projectID+"/stories"

   String body = "<story><story_type>feature</story_type><name>Story name</name><requested_by>James Kirk</requested_by></story>"

   URLFetchService fetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
   HTTPRequest request =  new HTTPRequest(pivotalUrl, HTTPMethod.POST, FetchOptions.Builder.withDeadline(30));
   request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("X-TrackerToken","putTokenHere"));
   request.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-type","application/xml"));

   HTTPResponse response = fetchService.fetch(request);
   if (response.getResponseCode() != 200) {
       // something went wrong
   }
   ```

Comment: i kind of added the body as request.setPayload(body.getBytes()); also does this stuff possible to test on local server as i heard lot of apis are just emulated

Comment: on printing response code etc i found it returns Could not create story as response code is:422
 which as per wiki means 422 Unprocessable Entity (WebDAV; RFC 4918)
The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors. any suggestions?

Comment: Yes you can simulate sending email from dev server: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/inboundmail`

Comment: sorry you took me wrong... when i am trying to send the story via url fetch i see 422 error as i mentioned above. any help on why this is happenning? i also posted at http://community.pivotaltracker.com/pivotal/topics/unable_to_create_story_via_gae_urlfetch?rfm=1 with my exact code

Comment: Sorry we do not know anything about curl . I pasted that from the pivtoalTracker page as kind of it resembles with the urlFetch java example. so not able to understand why i get this 422 error

Comment: First you should be able to perform Http requests by hand. When this works then put it in code using URLFetch.

Comment: Also I never used Pivotaltracker API, so I can't help you here.